# How to display location of users using ChartKick, Ahoy and Geocoding in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder, chartkick

I'm currently creating a website and I'd like to gather some metrics about users habits. I'm using the Ahoy gem to track visits and events and ChartKick to display the metircs.

So after looking up the documentation, I added this

```
 = geo_chart Ahoy::Visit.group(:country).count
```

I then needed to get some form of charting library so I imported Google's

```
 %script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"}
```

Now when I go on to the page, I see a map displayed, but it shows no countries

[Image of chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA3I6.png)

In my database I have a visit which I've added an IP, country and city name to. I would've thought that this would show up on the map, but it doesn't

Comment: Does your database contains the country as ISO 3166 ALPHA-2 code?

Comment: That worked, thank you. Is it normal that visiting localhost with Ahoy doesnt insert the code into the country column?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot say someting about Ahoy. Just knew that google needs the country in that type.